# How to assign ID for SQLite database object in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite

I practice in android kotlin coding and I create SQLite database. How I can to assign ID for object when it create? I think that I need to check are there objects and if no object I create object with ID 1. If there are objects I need to find last ID, is it right?
Database.kt:

```
class PartnerDB(context: Context):
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "partner.db", null, DB_VERSION) {
    var context: Context? = null
    init {
        this.context = context
    }
    companion object {
        val PARTNER = "partner"
        val DB_VERSION = 1
        val CREATE_TABLE_PARTNER = "CREATE TABLE person(pid INT, plogin TEXT, ppassword TEXT," +
                " pname TEXT, psale TEXT, pasale TEXT)"
        val SELECT_PARTNER = "SELECT * from partner"
    }
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db?.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PARTNER)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    fun insertIntoPartner(pid: Int, plogin: String, ppassword: String, pname: String,
                          psale: String, pasale: String): Boolean {
        var contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put("pid", pid)
        contentValues.put("plogin", plogin)
        contentValues.put("ppassword", ppassword)
        contentValues.put("pname", pname)
        contentValues.put("psale", psale)
        contentValues.put("pasale", pasale)

        val rowId = writableDatabase.insert(PARTNER, null, contentValues)
        return rowId>0
    }
```

How to assign ID in code? I want to assign ID automatically. If it's the first object ID must be 1. I don't have idea and thank for all suggestions.

Comment: Check out this: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1

Comment: @SemkoToruj how I understand `db.insertIntoPartner(NULL, "login", "info")` will create ID automatically? But I need in Databse.kt this code `val CREATE_TABLE_PARTNER = "CREATE TABLE partner(pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, plogin TEXT)"` Am I right?

Comment: I would guess so, but maybe not assign null to pid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** Define the pid column using `pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as per :-

```
val CREATE_TABLE_PARTNER = "CREATE TABLE person(pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, plogin TEXT, ppassword TEXT," +
            " pname TEXT, psale TEXT, pasale TEXT)"
```

- INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is a special case in that the column becomes an alias of the **rowid** column. You cannot use INT PRIMARY KEY as it will then not be an alias of the **rowid**.

**b)** Then use :-

```
fun insertIntoPartner(pid: Int, plogin: String, ppassword: String, pname: String,
                      psale: String, pasale: String): Boolean {
    var contentValues = ContentValues()
    //contentValues.put("pid", pid) /*<<<<< by not supplying the value the id will be generated by SQLite */
    contentValues.put("plogin", plogin)
    contentValues.put("ppassword", ppassword)
    contentValues.put("pname", pname)
    contentValues.put("psale", psale)
    contentValues.put("pasale", pasale)

    val rowId = writableDatabase.insert(PARTNER, null, contentValues)
    return rowId>0
```

- You would probably remove `pid: Int` from the function's signature as it is obsolete (unless there are situations where you want to specifiy pid (not recommended)).
- Note typically the id (pid) will be 1 greater than the last inserted. However, there is no guarantee that this will be the case. **pid** will not be renumbered if rows are deleted that are not the last rows. The intended purpose of the **rowid** or an alias thereof, is to be able to uniquely **ID**entify a row and for that row to be retrieved/accessed efficiently.

You may wish to read [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and or [Rowid Tables](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html)

Comment: I got another problem. I have a few activities with editText and how I can write info in database? I think that I need putExtra in activity like `putExtra("name", createname.text.toString()) and getExtra in other activity. But `intent.getStringExtra("name", createname.text.toString())` don't work. I found some info but it was for java. Can you help?

Comment: I think I found issue. Just replace `getStringExtra` to `extras?.getString`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in possible two ways explain below:

**Option - 1:** If you want `SQLite` handle the `ID` then you can do that below way. Here **INTEGER PRIMARY KEY** is important as `SQLite` automatically increment the `ID` using this.

```
val CREATE_TABLE_PARTNER = "CREATE TABLE partner(pid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
" plogin TEXT, ppassword TEXT, pname TEXT, psale TEXT, pasale TEXT)"

fun insertIntoPartner(plogin: String, ppassword: String, pname: String,
                      psale: String, pasale: String): Boolean {
    var contentValues = ContentValues()

    //contentValues.put("pid", pid)    -> pid will handle by sqlite

    contentValues.put("plogin", plogin)
    contentValues.put("ppassword", ppassword)
    contentValues.put("pname", pname)
    contentValues.put("psale", psale)
    contentValues.put("pasale", pasale)

    val rowId = writableDatabase.insert(PARTNER, null, contentValues)
    return rowId > 0
}
```

**Option - 2:** If you want to handle the `ID` by yourself [**Required when ID comes from server**], Then you have to follow the below way. First check the `DB` with the `ID` and if not present then `Insert`. If you want then you can also update the content of that specific `ID`.

```
val CREATE_TABLE_PARTNER = "CREATE TABLE partner(pid INTEGER, plogin TEXT," +
" ppassword TEXT, pname TEXT, psale TEXT, pasale TEXT)"

fun insertIntoPartner(pid: Int, plogin: String, ppassword: String, pname: String,
                      psale: String, pasale: String): Boolean {
    var contentValues = ContentValues()

    contentValues.put("pid", pid)
    contentValues.put("plogin", plogin)
    contentValues.put("ppassword", ppassword)
    contentValues.put("pname", pname)
    contentValues.put("psale", psale)
    contentValues.put("pasale", pasale)

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + PARTNER + " WHERE pid ='" + pid + "'";
    var rowId = 0

    try {
        cursor = writableDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //If you want then can update the content here
        } else {
            rowId = writableDatabase.insert(PARTNER, null, contentValues)
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rowId > 0;
}
```

Comment: AUTOINCREMENT is not important and is not recommended as it is inefficient as per *The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.* and *On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.* [SQLite Autoincrement](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) and